# Accessing static properties in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

How do you create static fields in a class and then access them from outside of that class in Sencha Touch 2?

For example I have created a simple singleton with a single static:

```
Ext.define('App.util.Config', {
    singleton: true,
    statics: {
        url: {
            USER: 'http://localhost:3436/api/user'
        }
    },
    config: { },
    constructor: function (config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        this.callParent([config]);
    }
});
```

I cannot access the USER field using **App.util.Config.url.USER** but with **App.util.Config.self.url.USER**.  Looking at a sample on the Sencha docs, it appears that I should be able able to access the field in the former way:

[See Statics Section in this link and how they access the Computer.InstanceCount field](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/class_system-section-3)

Comment: Working fine for me. Is App.util.Config.url undefined ? What does App.util.Config.self return ?

Comment: App.util.Config.url
 `undefined`
App.util.Config.self
 `function () {
                     return this.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
                 }`
App.util.Config.self.url.USER
 `"http://localhost:3436/api/user"`

Comment: One other piece of information that might be relevant, I am not `Ext.create(...)` this class, but requiring it in app.js `requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox',
        'App.data.ConnectionRouter',
        'App.util.Config'
    ],`

Answer (score 6):

I think this is what you want

```
Ext.define('App.util.Config', {
    singleton: true,
    statics: {
        url: {
            USER: 'http://localhost:3436/api/user'
        }
    },
    config: { },
    constructor: function (config) {
        var user=this.self.url.User;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is an old questions, but I stumbled upon it when looking for something else.

I believe that the problem is the use of `singleton:true`.  When this is used, then everything is static and there is no need to define the property explicitly as static.

The following should be the correct use:

```
Ext.define('App.util.Config', {
    singleton: true,
    url: {
        USER: 'http://localhost:3436/api/user'
    },
    config: { },
    constructor: function (config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        this.callParent([config]);
    }
});
```